# Retain line breaks in textareas in IE within JqGrid

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, jqgrid

I have a problem with all versions of IE saving the multiline formatting of a textarea within JqGrid. Unfortunately this is taking place in an MVC proprietary application so I can't set up a fiddle to demonstrate, however I can share the code and behavior. The textarea keeps the formatting as you see below, and when another cell in the grid is selected the the textarea changes to become a `<td>`, but the formatting is not kept. Chrome, Firefox and other browsers do retain the line breaks. I tried using `white-space: pre;` in CSS but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
<textarea style="height: 85px !important; width: 280px" rows="4" cols="35" wrap="hard" autocomplete="off" type="text">565456566
454654654
65465464456
546545464654</textarea>
```

Saved to:

```
<td title="5654565664&#10;54654654654&#10;6546445654&#10;6545464654">5654565664
5465465465465464456546545464654</td>
```

And then back to:

```
<textarea style="height: 85px !important; width: 280px" rows="4" cols="35" wrap="hard" autocomplete="off" type="text">56545656645465465465465464456546545464654</textarea>
```

**Update:** This grid is using JqGrid, and JqGrid's internal decoding mechanism apparently doesn't save breaks within textareas. It's interesting that modern browsers still saved the formatting.

[image]

Comment: Can you perhaps intercept the focus event for a `td` and specifically replace any newline characters before it turns into a `textarea`? Maybe it's an issue with `\n` vs `\r\n`?

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Any thoughts on why modern browsers are saving the breaks correctly? It would make more sense to me if all browsers acted the same way. If I can find a HTML/CSS solution that would be ideal but I'll explore that idea more if there aren't any other ideas.

Comment: Not sure, just an idea.  :)  I was just considering a possible "Microsoft" way of thinking about line break characters and a bug that could have developed from that. They should all accept `\n` as a newline (and they do seem to for the most part). Which version(s) of IE, by the way?

Comment: @PaulRedmond Glad you found the reason! I deleted my answer because you didn't mention JqGrid before, so the question changed completely from a general problem to a specific problem. Please always name all used frameworks or plugins if they might be related to the problem... Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I didn't know it was integrated in JqGrid, hence why I didn't mention it before. This was clarified by a developer and so I updated the question. However, I admit I should have investigated more before I posted the question originally.